# Can't get rid of indentation lines

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to get rid of these vertical lines that mark indentations. I already have this in settings.json `"workbench.tree.renderIndentGuides": "none"`. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you can also change the color of these guides to make it less prominent (high alpha value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

"editor.renderIndentGuides": false

Your setting applies for the indent lines within the folder hierarchy window